# Component with an email field that will POST back to a server when a user clicks a button and I need to validate the email address

Tags: reactjs, onclick, components, email-validation

I have a component with an email input and I need to figure out a way to check the email address to see if it's valid  like 'name@email.com' whenever a user clicks the next button on a form. I also need to send the value of that input back along with other data on the page and I'm not sure how to do either.

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import {
  Col, Row, Icon, Input, Tooltip
} from 'antd'
import Checkbox from '../elements/Checkbox'
import Markup from '../core/Markup'

const CustomerDetails = ({ customer }) => {
  const { contact = {}, account = {}, site = {} } = customer || {}
  const [disableInput, setDisableInput] = React.useState(false)
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState(contact.email)

  function clearInput() {
    setInputValue(' ')
  }

  function handleInputChange(event) {
    setInputValue(event.target.value)
  }

  function CheckboxClick() {
    if (!disableInput) {
      clearInput()
    }
    setDisableInput(prevValue => !prevValue)
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <h2>{account.name}</h2>
      <Row>
        <Col span={8}>
          <H3>
            <strong>Primary Contact:</strong>
          </H3>
          <P>{contact.name}</P>
          <P>{contact.phone}</P>
        </Col>
        <Col span={8}>
          <H3>
            <strong>Service Address:</strong>
          </H3>
          <P>{site.address1}</P>
          <P>{site.address2}</P>
          <P>
            {site.city},&nbsp;{site.state}&nbsp;
            {site.postalCode}
          </P>
        </Col>
        <Col span={8}>
          <H3>
            <strong>Billing Address:</strong>
          </H3>
          <StyledMarkup>{account.billingStreet}</StyledMarkup>
          <P>
            {account.billingCity},&nbsp;{account.billingState}
            &nbsp;
            {account.billingPostalCode}
          </P>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <br />
      <Row>
        <Col span={10}>
          <h4>
            PRIMARY CONTACT EMAIL &nbsp;
            <Tooltip
              placement="right"
              title={primaryContact}
            >
              <StyledTooltipIcon
                type="question-circle"
                theme="filled"
              />
            </Tooltip>
          </h4>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col span={8}>
          <StyledInput
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            disabled={disableInput}
          />
        </Col>
        <Col span={2} />
        <Col span={8}>
          <StyledCheckbox
            value={disableInput}
            onChange={CheckboxClick}
          /> EMAIL
          OPT OUT{' '}
          <Tooltip
            placement="right"
            title={emailText}
          >
            <StyledTooltipIcon
              type="question-circle"
              theme="filled"
            />
          </Tooltip>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <br />
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <StyledCheckbox /> EXEMPT
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <br />
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <H4>BUILDER</H4>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  )
}


CustomerDetails.propTypes = {
  customer: PropTypes.object
}

CustomerDetails.defaultProps = {
  customer: {}
}

const Container = styled.div`
  text-align: left;
`
const StyledCheckbox = styled(Checkbox)`
  &&& {
    background: white;

    input + span {
      width: 35px;
      height: 35px;
      border: 2px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.black};
    }

    input + span:after {
      width: 12.5px;
      height: 20px;
    }

    input:focus + span {
      width: 35px;
      height: 35px;
    }
  }
`

const StyledInput = styled(Input)`
  max-width: 100%;
  background: white;

  &&& {
    border: 2px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.black};
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 35px;
  }
`

const ErrorContainer = styled.div`
  span {
    text-align: center;
  }
`

const StyledTooltipIcon = styled(Icon)`
  color: #1571da;
`

const H3 = styled.h3`
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
`

const H4 = styled.h4`
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #1590ff;
`

const P = styled.p`
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
`

const StyledMarkup = styled(Markup)`
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
`

export default CustomerDetails
```

Comment: Please limit source code to what actually matters. What surgically don't you know how to do? Make a request? Handle the results? Other?

Comment: I'm not sure how to validate an email address to ensure that it's a valid address and I'm not sure how to send the user input back to the server

Comment: There are tons of tutorials regarding making requests; I'd start with one of those. Email validation is also well-documented and understood--start by doing some research first--as it stands now I think the question is far too broad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate an email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)